# Why is this JTextField not showing the contents?

Tags: java, jtextfield, mouselistener

I am trying to make a cheat code button for my game, and the displaying of it is all fine but I cannot correctly get the contents of this text field. This is the code for it:

```
cheats.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Class.console("DISPLAYED OPTIONPANE");
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(cheatCode, "Enter Code Here");

            Class.console("GOT STRING" + cheatCode.getText());
            if(cheatCode.getText().equals("testin")) {
                Class.console("testout");
            }
        }
```

I'm pretty much a beginner at this, so help? I can post everything else if needed.

P.S. Class.console() is a thing in my driver class. It's basically a shortened version of System.out.println()

Comment: Did you look at any online examples of how to use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showInputDialog()` method returns the value that was entered by the user. You should capture it into a variable. For example, do this:

```
String userInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Code Here");
```

The variable `userInputString` will be a string containing the value that you're looking for.

Comment: Great, +1, but use a different variable name, because `cheatCode` already appears to be the name of a field somewhere.

Comment: Makes sense, let me fix that.